# Given an array of strings, return another array containing all of its longest strings

Tags: javascript

1.What is wrong in my code?
This is the question: Given an array of strings, return another array containing all of its longest strings

```
function allLongestStrings(inputArray) {
       var newarr = [];

       if( inputArray.length == 1){
          return inputArray;
       }
        var longestWord = inputArray.sort(function(a, b) {
         return b.length - a.length;
       });
       for(var i = 0; i < longestWord.length; i++){
         if(longestWord[i] > longestWord[i+1]){
           newarr.push(longestWord[i]);
         }
       }

       return newarr;
    }
`
```

Comment: What exactly are your requirements? Are you just trying to sort the input array by length? Or trying to only take the n largest strings? Or trying to take only string longer than x?

Comment: your code sorts by length and keeps only one for each length. I don't understand your question. Please clarify what you want to have in result.

Comment: I need to return longest strings. For inputArray = ["abc", "cbd", "zzzzzz", "a","abcdef", "asasa","aaaaaa"], the output should be
allLongestStrings(inputArray) = ["zzzzzz","abcdef","aaaaaa"].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, the element at the 0 index of 'longestWord' will be the longest word.
Since you need all the elements that are longest, take the length of that first element in 'longestWord' variable, use a for loop to check all the elements which have length equal to the first element of 'longestWord', if the length is equal, push the element in the to be returned array:

```
    function allLongestStrings(inputArray) {
    var newarr = [];

    if( inputArray.length == 1){
      return inputArray;
    }
    var longestWord = inputArray.sort(function(a, b) {
     return b.length - a.length;
    });
    var lengthOfLongestWord = longestWord[0].length;//returns length of longest word


    for(var i = 0; i < longestWord.length; i++){
     if(longestWord[i].length == lengthOfLongestWord){
       newarr.push(longestWord[i]);
     }
    }

    return newarr;
    }


    var yolo = allLongestStrings(['hello', 'my ', 'friends']);
    console.log(yolo); //reuturns['friends']

    var yolo1 = allLongestStrings(['hey', 'whats', 'up', 'matey']);
    console.log(yolo1); //returns['whats','matey']
```

Comment: Deserves a vote just for working out what the OP wanted… the *for* loop to collect the longest words could be a *while* loop that terminates as soon as a shorter word is found. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one line code:

```
allLongestStrings = (inputArray) => {
    return inputArray.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
           .filter(m => m.length == inputArray[0].length)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def allLongestStrings(inputArray):
    m=[]
    for i in inputArray:
        m.append(len(i))
    count=max(m)
    l=[]
    for i in inputArray:
        if(len(i)==count):
            l.append(i)
    return l
```

First, store the sizes of elements in an array, then find the maximum of that array
then find the elements
and finally, store the elements in a separate list with the maximum size elements in the array

Answer (score 0):

This is not `javascript` code but you can follow this.

```
$first = allLongestStrings(["123", "2", "abc", "5"]);
print_r($first); //return["123", "abc"]
$second = allLongestStrings(["apple", "orange", "banna", "ABCDE","1234"]);
print_r($second); //return["apple", "banna", "ABCDE"]

function allLongestStrings($inputArray) {
    $l = 0;
    $final_array = array();
    $n = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($inputArray); $i++){
        if($l < strlen($inputArray[$i])){
            if($n > 0){
                $n = 0;
                $l = strlen($inputArray[$i]);
                $final_array[$n] = $inputArray[$i];
            } else {
                $l = strlen($inputArray[$i]);
                $final_array[$n] = $inputArray[$i];
            }
            $n++;
        } else if($l == strlen($inputArray[$i])){
            $final_array[$n] = $inputArray[$i];
            $n++;
        }
    }
    return $final_array;
}
```